# array to std::vector conversion

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I replaced a 3D array with a 3D std::vector in my code function and it's entering a infinite loop at compiling.If I had used a 3D array arr[ ][ ][ ] it would work perfect.Could you give me a hint,I really need to use a vector instead an array.Thanks:)

My initial code was:

```
bool sol(int arr[12][12][13]) {
    int row,col;

    if(!find_empty(arr,row,col)) return true;

    for(int i=1;i< arr[row][col].size();i++) {
        if(is_working(arr,row,col,arr[row][col][i]) ) {
            arr[row][col][0] = arr[row][col][i];

            if(sol(arr)) return true;

            arr[row][col][0] = 0;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

I replace **arr** with

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int> > > vec;
vec.resize(12);
for(int i=0;i<12;i++)
{
    vec[i].resize(12);
    for(int j=0;j<12;j++)
    {
        vec[i][j].resize(13);
        for(int k=0;k<13;k++)
            vec[i][j][k]=table[i][j][k];
    }
}
```

and now it's entering a infinite loop!The initial code has no errors,it's a simple backtracking.The problem appears after I replace **arr** with **vec**.Could you give me some advice.Sorry for the first posting!

Comment: "Could you guys please help me." No, not if you don't help us by making your code readable.

Comment: You should pass your vector by (const?) reference or it will copy the entire vector. If you want to modify the vector outside the function, this is actually required.

Comment: Yay now there are more magic numbers!  Also, please don't edit your question so dramatically after answers are posted.  You likely now need a new question.  Your segfault is fixed, accept an answer, answer your own original question, or close this question and ask a separate question.

Comment: I know it's a duplicate because I could could not delete it

Answer (score 3):

```
for(int i=1;i<=vec[row][col].size();i++)
```

should be

```
for(int i=1;i<vec[row][col].size();i++)
```

and unless you want to skip the first item in the vector you probably REALLY intend this:

```
for(int i=0;i<vec[row][col].size();i++)
```

and you could also consider using iterators, which make your code more flexible

```
for(auto it = vec[row][col].begin(); it != vec[row][col].end(); it++)
```

Also a style point, you reference vec[row][col] a lot within the same bit of code.  It helps readability to do something like this:

```
vector<someType>& tempVector = vec[row][col];
```

And then spread that reference throughout your code instead.

ALSO, and potentially most importantly:

```
k++;//Where on earth did you declare/define k and what else is it doing?????????
return false;
```